# Run-time error while converting rows of Excel sheet to separate XML files

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I want to export an xml file per row (see the example in the print screen).

I obtain following error

> Run-time error '2147024891 (80070005)':
> System error: -2147024891.

on

```
doc.Save sFile
```

I use the following code for reading the Excel sheet (Microsoft Excel for Mac Version 16.49) and creating a xml file:

```vb
Sub CustomerOutToXML()

 sTemplateXML = _
        "<?xml version='1.0'?>" + vbNewLine + _
        "<ENVELOPE>" + vbNewLine + _
            "<TRANSACTION>" + vbNewLine + _
                "<TYPE>" + vbNewLine + "</TYPE>" + vbNewLine + _
            "</TRANSACTION>" + vbNewLine + _
            "<CONTENT>" + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + _
                "<DATE>" + vbNewLine + "</DATE>" + vbNewLine + _
                "<SSCC>" + vbNewLine + "</SSCC>" + vbNewLine + _
                "<ORDER>" + vbNewLine + "</ORDER>" + vbNewLine + _
            "</CONTENT>" + vbNewLine + _
        "</ENVELOPE>"

 Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
 doc.async = False
 doc.validateOnParse = False
 doc.resolveExternals = False

 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
  lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

  For lRow = 2 To 7
   sFile = "/Users/xxx/Documents/" & .Cells(lRow, 1).Value & ".xml"
   Dim sDATE As String
   Dim sSSCC As String  'Not Long
   Dim sORDER As String

   sDATE = CStr(.Cells(lRow, 2).Value)
   sSSCC = .Cells(lRow, 3).Text ' <<< Not .Value
   sORDER = CStr(.Cells(lRow, 4).Value)
   sTransactionType = ActiveSheet.Name

   doc.LoadXML sTemplateXML
   doc.getElementsByTagName("DATE")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sDATE)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("TYPE")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sTransactionType)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("SSCC")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sSSCC)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("ORDER")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sORDER)


   doc.Save sFile
  Next

 End With

End Sub
```

Example of the Excel sheet:
[image]

Comment: Code works for me (on windows),  Suggest you check with `debug.print sFile` that  `sFile` is a valid file name/path and  `/Users/xxx/Documents/` is writeable to,

Comment: Oh thanks for your help and checking. Now I know at least that it is something with my Mac. Then I will try to debug with your command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your issue is not reproducible, consider some tips that may help you diagnose or resolve your issue:

1. Use `Option Explicit` at the very top of module (outside of `Sub` or `Function`) to be sure all objects are properly defined. Relatedly, place all `Dim` objects to top of subroutine or function to help readability.
2. Incorporate proper error handling with `On Error GoTo...` to capture runtime exceptions and appropriately exit the sub routine after unsetting objects with or without errors.
3. Avoid use of `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet` which can affect workflow if you have many workbooks open. Instead use actually assigned object or `ThisWorkbook` object. See this canonical Excel post, [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1422451) (where second answer discusses `Active*` methods).
4. Try using the early binding version of external libraries like MSXML that can expose useful error properties and enable Intellisense in VBA editor. Currently, you use late binding with `CreateObject`. If needing late binding for portability among many users, then ignore.

   ```vb
   Dim doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument

   Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
   ```
5. When using `With` blocks, follow through in all its properties. In fact, you can avoid use of `ActiveSheet`:

   ```vb
   sTransactionType = .Name
   ```