# Rows to individual xml files including content value - Permissions 70 error

Tags: excel, vba

I got a fix for this code on this thread and now Im getting a Permission 70 even if I save it to my desktop path.  Have tried multiple paths and still no luck.

[Rows to individual xml files including content value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73576230/rows-to-individual-xml-files-including-content-value?noredirect=1#comment129928408_73576230)

[image: ERROR MESSAGE WHEN RUNNING]

```
Sub Export()

sTemplateXML = _
        "<data>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <Name/>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <AXCustNum/>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <CustomerName/>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <Title/>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <Folder/>" + vbNewLine + _
        "</data>" + vbNewLine

 Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
 doc.async = False
 doc.validateOnParse = False
 doc.resolveExternals = False

With Sheets("SAL Checked File Names 1.9")
  lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

 For lRow = 2 To lLastRow
   sname = .Cells(lRow, 1).Value
   saxcustnum = .Cells(lRow, 2).Value
   scustomername = .Cells(lRow, 3).Value
   sTitle = .Cells(lRow, 4).Value
   sFolder = .Cells(lRow, 5).Value
   
   
   doc.LoadXML sTemplateXML
   doc.getElementsByTagName("Name")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sname)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("AXCustNum")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(saxcustnum)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("CustomerName")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(scustomername)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("Title")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sTitle)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("Folder")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sFolder)

   doc.Save sFolder
   Next
   
   End With
 
End Sub
```

I think it is erroring at "doc.Save sFolder"

Comment: Tried moving after NEXT still giving Run-time error '70': permission denied

Comment: Is `sFolder` a complete valid file path and filename?

Comment: What value has _sFolder_ when the error occurs?

Comment: Direct to my desktop, but I've also tried every other file path too to help - Im on MAC right now so this one is /Users/salliefrancis/Desktop/SAL AX Document Conversion

Comment: Here's a sample https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rNqRkTMJTGQn7DvURaivmwCLJWechv8U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try to use a complete file path (folder, filename, file extension).

Comment: Shrotter that worked.  I needed to change the column in excel with full filepath which I updated to include document name and then  with .xml at the end.  You wouldn't believe how long I obsessed over this today.  So good to have an outcome.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Shrotter advice worked.  I needed to change the column in excel with full filepath which I updated to include document name and then with .xml at the end. You wouldn't believe how long I obsessed over this today. So good to have an outcome. Thank you –